# Want to multiple columns from the_content in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want to Split wordpress Bydefault content in 3 columns through wordcount not by letter count. what is the exact code for this
This is my functions.php code but it gives only 2 part of a paragraph... But i want 3 part of a paragraph. How to do it?

functions.php:

```
function my_multi_col_v2($content){
    // run through a couple of essential tasks to prepare the content
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);

    // the first "more" is converted to a span with ID
    $columns = preg_split('/(<span id="more-\d+"><\/span>)|(<!--more-->)<\/p>/', $content);
    $col_count = count($columns);

    if($col_count > 1) {
        for($i=0; $i<$col_count; $i++) {
            // check to see if there is a final </p>, if not add it
            if(!preg_match('/<\/p>\s?$/', $columns[$i]) )  {
                $columns[$i] .= '</p>';
            }
            // check to see if there is an appending </p>, if there is, remove
            $columns[$i] = preg_replace('/^\s?<\/p>/', '', $columns[$i]);
            // now add the div wrapper
            $columns[$i] = '<div class="dynamic-col-'.($i+1).'">'.$columns[$i].'</div>';
        }
        $content = join($columns, "\n").'<div class="clear"></div>';
    }
    else {
        // this page does not have dynamic columns
        $content = wpautop($content);
    }
    // remove any left over empty <p> tags
    $content = str_replace('<p></p>', '', $content);
    return $content;
}

css: /* dynamic columns */
div.dynamic-col-1 { float: left; width: 38%; padding-right: 2%;}
div.dynamic-col-2 { float: left; width: 38%;padding-right: 2%;}
div.dynamic-col-3 { float: left; width: 20%;}
div.clear { clear: both; }
And
I replace " the_content()" tag with the following code:
$content = get_the_content('',FALSE,''); // arguments remove 'more' text
echo my_multi_col_v2($content);
```